# Http client big queries

Tags: c#

I'm trying  to send a big query from as api string.
If my query is too big it doesnt send it in my http listener.

here is my code:

```
  var table = db.Table<OrderPreviewClass>();
        query = "";


        foreach (var item in table)
            query += "Insert into InventoryTransTemp (InventoryItemID,CategoryID,Name,Quantity,Price,ExtrasPrice,RealPrice,Extras,UserID,UserName,TableName,DiscountPrice,CashierUserID,PrintFiscal,Printed) values ('" + item.InventoryItemID + "','" + item.CategoryID + "','" + item.Description + "','" + item.Quantity + "','" + item.Price.Replace(",", ".") + "','" + item.ExtrasPrice.Replace(",", ".") + "','" + item.RealPrice.Replace(",", ".") + "','" + item.Extras + "','" + MyUserID + "','" + MyUserName + "','" + MyTableName + "','" + item.Price.Replace(",", ".") + "')";


        HttpClient hTTPClient = new HttpClient();
        hTTPClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000);

        var uri = new Uri(string.Format("http://192.168.1.15:8282/" + query));
        var response = await hTTPClient.GetAsync(uri);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();


        }
```

## http listener

```
HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
        listener.Prefixes.Add("http://192.168.1.15:8282/");
        listener.Start();
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {


                HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();
                string methodName = Convert.ToString(context.Request.Url);
                MessageBox.Show(methodName);
                string Response = "Response";

                HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;
                string responseString = Convert.ToString(Response);
                byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString);
                response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
                System.IO.Stream output = response.OutputStream;
                output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                output.Close();
                //MessageBox.Show(methodName);
            }
        }).Start();
```

listener is working if i will send just one small string after my url

Comment: sending a SQL statement through a uri seems like it would open you up to SQL injection attacks. I  think you may want to consider making a parameterized query and just pass the parameter values in your api call.

Comment: "If my query is too big" -- what does that even mean?

Comment: Be aware of sending queries in url because maximum URL length is 2,083 characters. Also send query as url paramater is bad solution IMHO

Comment: No nothing. I just dont get any answer from http listener. If i will send a smaller string then it send it.

Comment: Please tell me this is not on a public facing website....

Comment: No it is not a web site. It has to do with a local server and a mobile phone(through wifi). What other option do i have?

Comment: 1: maximum url length, 2: the query string is escaped after new Uri()?

Answer (score 0):

Since the SQL statement is static do not pass the whole statement in the uri, build the sql statement in the listener and send only the values that will be injected into the sql statement.  This not only reduces the size of the uri but also greatly lowers the risk of sql injection or revealing database schema.